# Workflow and Infopath

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, infopath

Do I need Infopath installed locally to edit forms in a workflow for sharepoint?

Comment: The question is not clear to me anymore, do you want to be able to fill in workflow forms when they are presented to you in the site. If so, you won't need InfoPath. 
If however, you want to change the form itself, then you do need InfoPath. (i.e. custom workflows with custom forms etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Authoring InfoPath forms**

If a person needs to create a new Infopath form or needs to change the layout of the existing form one needs to use InfoPath client.

The form layout and data structure is saved as XML so one might try to edit it but I would recommend you not to mess with it.

**Filling forms**

In order to fill the forms there are two scenarios:

1. User fills a form via web browser (InfoPath client is not required)
2. User fills a form via InfoPath client

The first option does sound interesting but limitations do apply:

- You must purchase MOSS Enterprise license (for difference between SharePoint editions check this: [overview](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2007/08/which-sharepoint-edition-is-right-for-you) or [details here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/FX101758881033.aspx#5)). There is an option to purchase a dedicated Forms Server.
- Infopath as web form does not support all the features as the Infopath client form
- Although web forms sound very appealing, my experience taught me that most important features are not available in the web edition. [Check here for detailed list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath/HA102040851033.aspx).

**Default workflow forms**

Your original question is not clear, but if you are talking about editing default workflow forms like Approval workflow form (which is InfoPath) there is no easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need InfoPath as long as your forms are browser-enabled and you are running on MOSS (to use the InfoPath Forms Services).

If you are on plain WSS, then you will need InfoPath installed to fill out forms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is necessary if the forms are stored in a SharePoint document library.

Do you mean to edit individual forms, or to design a form?

Comment: Then, no, I don't think you need InfoPath for that. I think the form will render to HTML with no help needed from InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do, it will be rendered as HTML in the site, but to edit it, you need a copy of infopath.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just a user, and it's a web form, then you do not need to install the software, Otherwise, you should. It depends on what form the InfoPath display.

If you are a developer, you must install it locally so as to edit the template and deploy it.